# Add reflection on Python ray tracing code

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, raytracing

This is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
import numpy.testing as nptest
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def normalize(x):
    return x/np.linalg.norm(x)
    
def intersect_Scene(ray, obj):
    if obj.get("type") == "plan":
        return intersect_Plane(ray,obj)
    #"Added" Mudança de if para elif
    elif obj.get("type") == "sphere":
        return intersect_Sphere(ray,obj)
    #"Added" else e return np.inf... 
    else:
        return np.inf

def intersect_Plane(ray, plane):
    O = ray.get("origine")
    d = ray.get("direction")
    p = plane.get("position")
    n = plane.get("vectN")
    t = (np.dot(p-O,n))/(np.dot(d,n))
    if t>0 :
        return t
    else: 
        return np.inf

def intersect_Sphere(ray, sphere):
    O = ray.get("origine")
    D = ray.get("direction")
    C = sphere.get("centre")
    r = sphere.get("rayon")
    a = np.dot(D,D)
    b = 2*np.dot(D,O-C)
    c = np.dot(O-C,O-C)-r**2
    delta = b**2-4*a*c
    if delta>0 :
        t1 = (-b-np.sqrt(delta))/(2*a)
        t2 = (-b+np.sqrt(delta))/(2*a)
        return min(t1,t2)
    if delta==0 :
        t3=(-b)/(2*a)
        return t3
    else :
        return np.inf

def get_Normal(obj,M):
    if obj.get("type") == "sphere" :
        n = np.array(M-obj.get("centre"))
    elif obj.get("type") == "plan" :
        n = obj.get("vectN")
    return n

def create_Ray(O, D):
    ray = {"origine": np.array(O), "direction": np.array(D)} 
    return ray

def create_sphere(C, r, Col, Dif, Spec, cr, i):
    sphere = {"type": "sphere", "centre": np.array(C), "rayon" : float (r), "index": int(i), "ambiant": np.array(Col), "diffuse": np.array(Dif),"reflection_index":float(cr), "specular": np.array(Spec) }
    return sphere

def create_plane(P, n, Col, Dif, Spec, cr, i):
    plane = {"type": "plan", "position": np.array(P), "vectN": np.array(n), "index": int(i), "ambiant": np.array(Col), "diffuse": np.array(Dif), "reflection_index":float(cr), "specular": np.array(Spec) } 
    return plane

def rayAt(ray,t):
    O = ray.get("origine")
    d = ray.get("direction")
    rayon = O+t*d
    return rayon

def Is_in_Shadow(obj,P,N):
    PosLum = light.get("position")
    L = [] 
    lPL = normalize(PosLum-P)
    PE = P + N*acne_eps
    rayTest = create_Ray(PE, lPL)
    for obj_test in scene :
        if obj_test.get("index") != obj.get("index"):
            i = intersect_Scene(rayTest,obj_test)
            if i != np.inf:
                L.append(obj_test)
    if len(L)==0:
        return True
    else :
        return False

def reflected_ray(dirRay,N):
    return dirRay - 2 * np.dot(dirRay, N) * N 

def eclairage(obj,light,P):
    
    PosLum = light.get("position")
    l = normalize(PosLum-P)
    n1 = get_Normal(obj,P)
    n = normalize(n1) #Lembrar mais tarde sobre não retornar negativo

    cd = obj["ambiant"]*light["ambiant"]+obj["diffuse"]* light["diffuse"]* np.dot(l,n) + np.array([0.05,0.05,0.05])
    c = normalize(C-P)
    c1 = normalize(l+c)
    c2 = np.dot(c1,n)
    ct = cd + obj["specular"] * light["specular"] * c2**(materialShininess/4)
    return ct

def compute_reflection(rayTest,depth_max,col=np.zeros((3))):
    diretion=rayTest.get("direction")
    c=1 
    for k in range(1,depth_max):
        t = np.inf
        obj={}
        for obj_test in scene :
            i = intersect_Scene(rayTest,obj_test)
            if t>i:
                t=i
                obj = obj_test
        if t==np.inf:
            break #return None,None,None,[0,0,0]
        else :
            obj=obj
            M = t
            P = rayAt(rayTest, t)
            N = get_Normal(obj,M)
            ME = M + N*acne_eps
            col_ray=obj['ambiant']+obj['diffuse']+obj['specular']
            # col *= col_ray
            col += obj['diffuse'] * light['diffuse'] * np.dot(col_ray, N)
            col += obj['specular'] * light['specular'] * np.dot(N, ME)**(materialShininess/4)
            col +=c*col_ray

            # PosLum = light.get("position")
            # l = normalize(PosLum-ME)
            # n = normalize(N)

            # cd = obj["ambiant"]*light["ambiant"]+obj["diffuse"]* light["diffuse"]* np.dot(l,n) + np.array([0.05,0.05,0.05])
            # col_ray = normalize(C-ME)
            # c1 = normalize(l+c)
            # c2 = np.dot(c1,n)
            # col = cd + obj["specular"] * light["specular"] * c2**(materialShininess/4)
            
            reflect_ray =reflected_ray(diretion,N) # Calculate reflected light
            #c += trace_ray(create_Ray(ME, reflect_ray))
            
            diretion=reflected_ray(diretion,N)
            rayTest=reflected_ray(diretion,N)
        return col

def trace_ray(ray):
    t = np.inf
    obj={}
    for obj_test in scene :
        i = intersect_Scene(ray,obj_test)
        if t>i:
            t=i
            obj = obj_test
    if t==np.inf:
        return None,None,None,[0,0,0]
    else :
        P = rayAt(ray, t)
        N = get_Normal(obj,P)
        shadow = Is_in_Shadow(obj, P, N)
        if shadow == False:
            return None,None,None,[0,0,0]
        reflect_ray =reflected_ray(ray.get("direction"),N)
        col_ray =eclairage(obj,light,P) # se eclairage for usada haverá complicações...
        reflexion=compute_reflection(ray,depth_max,col_ray)
        return obj, P, N, reflexion

w = 800
h = 600
img = np.zeros((h, w, 3)) # image vide : que du noir
r = float(w) / h
S = (-1., -1. / r , 1., 1. / r )

col = np.array([0.2, 0.2, 0.7])  # couleur de base
C = np.array([0., 0.1, 1.1])  # Coordonée du centre de la camera.
Q = np.array([0,0.3,0])  # Orientation de la caméra
img = np.zeros((h, w, 3)) # image vide : que du noir

light = {"position": np.array([5,5,0]), "ambiant": np.array([5/100,5/100,5/100]), "diffuse": np.array([1,1,1]), "specular": np.array([1,1,1])}

materialShininess = 50
acne_eps = 1e-4
depth_max = 10

scene = [create_sphere([.75, -.3, -1.], # Position
                         .6, # Rayon
                         np.array([1. , 0.6, 0. ]), # ambiant
                         [0.9, 0.6, 0.], # diffuse
                         [1, 1, 1], # specular
                         0.2, # reflection index
                         1), # index
         create_plane([0., -.9, 0.], # Position
                        [0, 1, 0], # Normal
                        np.array([0.145, 0.584, 0.854]), # ambiant
                        [0.145, 0.584, 0.854], # diffuse
                        [1, 1, 1], # specular
                        0.7, # reflection index
                        5), # index
         ]

for i, x in enumerate(np.linspace(S[0], S[2], w)):
    if i % 10 == 0:
        print(i / float(w) * 100, "%")
    for j, y in enumerate(np.linspace(S[1], S[3], h)):
        a,b,c,d = trace_ray(create_Ray(C, np.array([x-C[0],y-C[1],-C[2]])))
        img[h - j - 1, i, :] = np.clip(d, 0, 1)

plt.imsave('figImBasic2.png', img)
```

If you run the code, you will see an image with a sphere without any reflection on the floor or the sphere itself, my purpose it to add reflection using the function 'compute_reflection' I guess I need to somehow call 'trace_ray' inside 'compute_reflection' so that it starts the loop of reflection but I can't see how.

Any contributions would be appreciated.

Comment: i notice `compute_reflection` has its return statement inside a for-loop, perhaps preventing the full execution